# EU Blue Card with changing employers within Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card, visa-change

I've worked in Germany for 3 years with the same employer/title. I had an EU blue card for 15 months when I was first here then lost it when I renewed my permit (after an increase in income eligibility threshold which I no longer met).
If I change jobs to a new employer, and qualify for the card again, does the past period count towards the permanent residence, i.e. Niederlassungserlaubnis , eligibility period (33 months or 21 months with a B level German)? Or do I have to start all over again (at which point it no longer matters because I would be automatically eligible for the permanent residency if I've been working in Germany for 5 years).

I've already asked at the local ausländerbehörde, but they always seem to so confused with my questions and can't give direct answers.

Comment: To be eligible for the *Niederlassungserlaubnis*, you had to hold an *Aufenthaltserlaubnis* for five years. A short break up to one year is allowed. But honestly, if the officials can't give you an answer, it's very likely you are missing crucial information, or tell contradicting things, and we cannot either.